# Namespaces and records in erlang

Tags: namespaces, erlang, record

Erlang obviously has a notion of *namespace*, we use things like `application:start()` every day.

I would like to know if there is such a thing as namespace for records. In my application I have defined record **user**. Everything was fine until I needed to include `rabbit.hrl` from RabbitMQ which also defines **user**, which is conflicting with mine.

Online search didn't yield much to resolve this. I have considered renaming my user record and prefixing it with something, say "myapp_user". This will fix this particular issue, until I suspect I hit another conflict say with my record "session".

What are my options here? Is adding a prefix `myapp_` to all my records a good practice, or is there a real support for namespaces with records and I am just not finding it?

**EDIT:** Thank you everyone for your answers. What I've learned is that the records are global. The accepted answer made it very clear. I will go with adding prefixes to all my records, as I have expected.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would argue that Erlang has no namespaces whatsoever. Modules are global (with the exception of a very unpopular extension to the language), names are global (either to the node or the cluster), pids are global, ports are global, references are global, etc.

Everything is laid flat. The namespacing in Erlang is thus done by convention rather than any other mean. This is why you have `<appname>_app`, `<appname>_sup`, etc. as module names. The registered processes also likely follow that pattern, and ETS tables, and so on.

However, you should note that records themselves are not global things: as [JUST MY correct OPINION](https://stackoverflow.com/users/282658/just-my-correct-opinion) has put it, records are simply a compiler trick over tuples. Because of this, they're local to a module definition. Nobody outside of the module will see a record unless they also include the record definition (either by copying it or with a header file, the later being the best way to do it).

Now I could argue that because you need to include `.hrl` files and record definitions on a per-module basis, there is no such thing as namespacing records; they're rather *scoped* in the module, like a variable would be. There is no reason to ever namespace them: just include the right one.

Of course, it could be the case that you include record definitions from two modules, and both records have the same name. If this happens, renaming the records with a prefix might be necessary, but this is a rather rare occurrence in my experience.

Note that it's also generally a bad idea to expose records to other modules. One of the problems of doing so is that all modules depending on yours now get to include its `.hrl` file. If your module then change the record definition, you will have to recompile every other module that depends on it. A better practice should be to implement functions to interact with the data. Note that get(Key, Struct) isn't always a good idea. If you can pick meaningful names (age, name, children, etc.), your code and API should make more sense to readers.

Comment: Modules are global, but form a namespace for functions, no?

Comment: They do. It's a very flat namespace, though.

Answer (score 5):

You'll either need to name all of your records in a way that is unlikely to conflict with other records, or you need to just not use them across modules. In most circumstances I'll treat records as opaque data structures and add functionality to the module that defines the record to access it. This will avoid the issue you've experienced.

Answer (score 3):

I may be slapped down soundly by I GIVE TERRIBLE ADVICE here with his deeper knowledge of Erlang, but I'm pretty sure there is no namespaces for records in Erlang.  The record name is just an atom grafted onto the front of the tuple that the compiler builds for you behind the scenes.  (Records are pretty much just a hack on tuples, you see.)  Once compiled there **is** no meaningful "namespace" for a record.

For example, let's look at this record.

```
-record(branch, {element, priority, left, right}).
```

When you instantiate this record in code...

```
#branch{element = Element, priority = Priority, left = nil, right = nil}.
```

...what comes out the other end is a tuple like this:

```
{branch, Element, Priority, nil, nil}
```

That's all the record is at this point.  There **is** no actual "record" object and thus namespacing doesn't really make any sense.  The name of the record is just an atom tacked onto the front.  In Erlang it's perfectly acceptable for me to have that tuple and another that looks like this:

```
{branch, Twig, Flower}
```

There's no problem at the run-time level with having both of these.

But...

Of course there is a problem having these in your code as records since the compiler doesn't know which `branch` I'm referring to when I instantiate.  You'd have to, in short, do the manual namespacing you were talking about if you want the records to be exposed in your API.

That last point is the key, however.  Why are you exposing records in your API?  The code I took my branch record from uses the record as a purely opaque data type.  I have a function to build a branch record and **that** is what will be in my API if I want to expose a branch at all.  The function takes the `element`, `priority`, etc. values and returns a record (read: a tuple).  The user has no need to know about the contents.  If I had a module exposing a (biological) tree's structure, it too could return a tuple that happens to have the atom `branch` as its first element without any kind of conflict.

Personally, to my tastes, exposing records in Erlang APIs is code smell.  It may sometimes be necessary, but most of the time it should remain hidden.

Comment: Or you may be corrected by me :) With luck Records will be more permanent in R15.

Comment: I deal with the here and now, not with the nebulous future.  ;)  But yeah, it would be nice to have records become first class citizens instead of crude compiler hacks in the future.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one record namespace and unlike functions and macros there can only be one record with a name. However, for *record fields* there is one namespace per record, which means that there is no problems in having fields with the same name in different records. This is one reason why the record name must always be included in every record access.